# Text Missing On Checkbox Component for Swing After Adding Action

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcheckbox, windowbuilder

I'm writing a simple Swing app. I tried adding a checkbox as listed below. Once I added the actionHandler **loadPickers** the name **Foo** disappeared from where it was sitting next to the right of **chckbxNewCheckBox**. I tried adding a call to **setHideActionText()**, but now nothing displays.

```
JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Foo");
chckbxNewCheckBox.setToolTipText("");
chckbxNewCheckBox.setName("");
chckbxNewCheckBox.setHideActionText(true);
chckbxNewCheckBox.setAction(loadPickers);
mainPanel.add(chckbxNewCheckBox, "flowy,cell 0 1");
```

If I change it to this it works properly. I see the text "Foo".

```
JCheckBox chckbxNewCheckBox = new JCheckBox("Foo");
chckbxNewCheckBox.setToolTipText("");
chckbxNewCheckBox.setName("");
chckbxNewCheckBox.setHideActionText(true);
chckbxNewCheckBox.setAction(loadPickers);
chckbxNewCheckBox.setText("Foo"); //THIS DOES NOT WORK IF IT COMES BEFORE SET ACTION
mainPanel.add(chckbxNewCheckBox, "flowy,cell 0 1");
```

I've included the action here for completeness. Why does it work this way? Am I missing something here? Currently I'm using the WindowBuilder plugin for Eclipse with the Mig layout system (which I really like). Unfortunately I haven't figure out if there's a way to make WindowBuilder use the .setText() method instead of using the constructor. Any help on what I'm doing wrong, any insight on why this behavior exists like this, or a good workaround for WindowBuilder would be great.

```
private class LoadPickers extends AbstractAction {
    public LoadPickers() {
        //putValue(NAME, "SwingAction_2");
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Some short description");
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in the JavaDoc of [AbstractButton.setAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setAction%28javax.swing.Action%29):

> Setting the Action results in immediately changing all the properties described in [Swing Components Supporting Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#buttonActions). Subsequently, the button's properties are automatically updated as the Action's properties change.

So all the following properties can be impacted by setting an action:

- enabled
- toolTipText
- actionCommand
- mnemonic
- text
- displayedMnemonicIndex
- icon (NA for JCheckBox)
- accelerator (NA for JCheckBox)
- selected

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess I don't really understand the point of having the text for the action either over-write or null out the text value of the button it's being applied to. I have a single action handler that is agnostic to which checkbox is clicked, so I want to register all my checkboxes with that single action handler. In this case I have to do a bunch of extra legwork unless I make three separate action handlers for each button. It seems like inherenting the values from the action handler discourages reuse of these action handlers?